# Chilkat Events on downloading a directory sftp (Vb.NET)

Tags: sftp, chilkat

i am using the chilkat library accessing my sftp server, which works fine. I have, lets say 4 methods, upload/download a file, which all calls on a percentdone event (supplied by chilkat) which works fine. Then i have an upload/Download directory, the upload has  the percentdone event, so again, fine. BUT, the download directory seems not to have this event.

Anyone had this problem? or is this a case that the event is just not accessible on this method in chilkat - (syncTreeDownload)

- events are all called in the same way throughout the three methods, and by debugging the event is not being called by only the download dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent-done event is not possible on the SyncTreeDownload because the entire remote directory tree would first need to be traversed to determine what is to be downloaded so that a calculation could be performed.  It was decided that this potentially large overhead was not acceptable and thus percentage-completion events are not available for SyncTreeDownload.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! will adjust accordingly!